# issue with forms authentication - Unable to redirect from login page to home page after authentication

Tags: c#, .net, sharepoint-2010, forms-authentication

In Sharepoint 2010 we created a web application with classic authentication and started developing it. Later, we want to implement forms authentication to our project, so I created a new SharePoint Web Application with form based authentication enabled. I took the backup of the old site (classic auth.) and restored to the new site (fba). I implemented forms authentication by following the below link:

[Configuring Forms Based Authentication for SharePoint 2010 using IIS7](http://donalconlon.wordpress.com/2010/02/23/configuring-forms-base-authentication-for-sharepoint-2010-using-iis7/)

I created a custom sign-in page. After entering valid credentials the user is not redirected to the Home page. Authentication is happening properly but it is not redirecting to the home page. When I click on the login button, it is again loading the same login page. Please find the below code for authenticating and redirecting to home page:

```
protected void btnLogin2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if (Membership.ValidateUser(txtUserId.Value, txtPassword.Value))
  {
    string link = "http://ejudnam:36414/sites/Prototype/Dashboard/Pages/default.aspx");

    Response.Redirect(link);

    //I tried with the below line also but it is of no use
    // SPUtility.Redirect(link, SPRedirectFlags.Default, this.Context);
  }  
  else
  {
    lblMessage.Text = "Login Failed.";
  }
}
```

We are unable to figure out the issue. I tried so many solutions but they are of no use.

Answer (score 2):

Please Use [SPClaimsUtility](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.identitymodel.spclaimsutility.authenticateformsuser.aspx) for Authorization of Users in Claims based application.

> Add the **Microsoft.SharePoint.IdentityModel** DLL reference from .\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.SharePoint.IdentityModel\14.0.0.0__71e9bce111e9429c \Microsoft.SharePoint.IdentityModel.dll to access SPClaimsUtility

than try this:

```
  SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
        {
           bool status = SPClaimsUtility.AuthenticateFormsUser(Context.Request.UrlReferrer, txtUserId.Value, txtPassword.Value);
           if (status)
              {
               string link = "http://ejudnam:36414/sites/Prototype/Dashboard/Pages/default.aspx";
              Response.Redirect(link);
              }
        });
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer. I used your code. I tried to login as admin/user but it is throwing 'Access denied' error. Am i missing something? Please help me out.

Comment: may be you have to give permission for those users which is you want to login..and which line throwing error?

Comment: check it out this link:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7778223/sharepoint-claims-based-authentication-new-user-use-case hops its helps.

Comment: It was throwing error at 'Response.Redirect(link)' line. I am unable to view the top ribbon because of forms authentication. So I can't give the permissions to the users. I assume that users doesn't have access to the default page of 'Dashboard'. How do I give permission to default.aspx page to the users without having access to the top ribbon? Can you tell me the permission settings in case of forms-authentication?

Comment: first login with Window authetication than after give permission of the fba users.thats it and try this : `response.redirect(SPContext.Current.Web.Url + "/Pages/default.aspx")`;

Comment: I am unable to login with Windows authentication. It is accepting only forms authentication. As i said before, i am unable to see 'Site Actions' link. So I couldn't set the permission to the users.

Comment: dude..if you are not able to see ribbon so there are another way is go to `central administration > Administration mngt > change site collection administartor >` select your site collection than add your fba user as Site Administrator.

Comment: I have already given the site collection administrator but it is throwing the white page with error 'Access denied'